# Jest - TypeError: Cannot read property 'projects' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

So I am starting to do unit testing of my React-Native application. I just wanted to try the first test and I immediately get errors.

Here is what my test looks like:

```js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Index from '../index.ios.js';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Index />
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

and here is my package JSON

```js
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "npm install && react-native link && react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "anymatch": "^1.3.0",
    "native-base": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-local-notifications": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.15.2",
    "react-native-notifications": "^1.1.11",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.10.3",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The error I get is this :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'projects' of undefined
at /Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:106:25
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:1:260)
at /Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:1:490
at Promise (<anonymous>)
at /Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:1:171
at module.exports (/Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:139:50)
at Object.run (/Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:40:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:14:25)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
```

I literally have no idea why. I have looked around and no one has experienced the same error as this.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Also just as a general point, I find it easier to just use [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) rather than `renderer.create` etc.

Comment: Is "projects" a property in your <Index> component by chance?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'projects' of undefined
    at /Users/grantherman/Desktop/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:106:25

Comment: Projects is not in my <Index />

Answer (score 0):

Under `jest` in your `package.json`, try adding `"testEnvironment": "jsdom"`

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
}
```

Comment: like this? 
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
}

Comment: almost `"jest": { "preset": "react-native" , "testEnvironment": "jsdom" }`

Comment: Ah, sorry. The only suggestions I have are to run `react-native unlink` then run `react-native link`. Initially, the error looks like it might need a mock, but what's weird is it looks to be failing on Jest Cli, but here is a link to the facebook docs on [mocking native components](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#mock-native-modules-using-jestmock). You might try that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see jest-cli in your packages.json. I had the exact same issue with reactjs. Installing jest-cli (I only had jest) fixed the issue.